# Straight UV island but stretched checker texture. How to solve?

Tags: uv, seams

The UV island of the detail looks fairly straight (selected in the screenshot; I had even aligned it and did the 'follow active quads' thing). Yet the texture of the face is stretched heavily, and I don't know why it is so and how to solve it as the UV island looks OK.

[image]

What is wrong and what to do? Thank you all.

Comment: this is because of the inner triangulation of the face, subdivide your mesh a bit (begin with some vertical loopcuts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your UV is stretched it will also stretch the inner triangles that make your quad:

[image]

To fix that, subdivide your mesh until the inner triangulations become unnoticeable:

[image]